# What child NPCs appear in official published adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, npc

I'm working on a supplement for **Strixhaven** where the players take the roles of counselors at a magical summer camp. I wanted to list some potential tie-ins to other products, specifically where child NPCs from other published scenarios could be introduced as campers. I'm aware of a few somewhat notable young NPCs from published products (such as the Cassalanter Twins and the Urchins from **Waterdeep: Dragon Heist**, or Arabelle and the Martikov sons from **Curse of Strahd**), but I'd like to list as many tie-ins to published products as possible.

Can anyone add any significant child NPCs (roughly 8-14 years old, or the approximate racial equivalent) from published D&D 5e adventures?

I'd need to limit it to titles that can be referenced in DMs Guild products, which limits it to the Forgotten Realms, Ravenloft, Eberron, Ravnica, Theros, and Arcavios (Strixhaven).

Comment: Rather than having 20 answers suggesting 20 different kiddos from different adventures, I've started a CW answer with the candidates you provided in the question, and will add some as I have time.

Comment: Given that elves age physically at the same speed as humans but aren't considered adults until age 100, I think there's some room for comedic misunderstandings of "children's summer camp".

Comment: *fully mature 14 year old monster race has entered the chat.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*

- [Shorah Hevrun](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/elturel-has-fallen#GhastlyMeal)

### *Candlekeep Mysteries*

- [Gailby Smallstone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/candlekeep-mysteries#GailbySmallstone)
- [Ashlan](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cm/sarah-of-yellowcrest-manor#B11Cells)

### *Critical Role: Call of the Netherdeep*

- [Gothby and Chespa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cotn/the-leave-taking#CaravanStopLocations) (they're 3 and 5 respectively, but goblins are adults at 8—and even Chespa (the 3-year-old) is literate and "speaks as well as an adult")

### *Curse of Strahd*

- [Arabelle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/the-lands-of-barovia#RoleplayingArabelle)
- [Brom and Bray Martikov](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/the-town-of-vallaki#KeepersoftheFeather)
- [Rose and Thorn Durst](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/appendix-b-death-house#RoseandThorn) (kind of)
- [Yeska](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/the-town-of-vallaki#N1StAndralsChurch) (probably)

### *Dragon of Icespire Peak*

- [Pell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/doip/falcons-hunting-lodge#LocationOverview)

### *Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden*

- [Silja and Finn Dejarr](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/dougans-hole#HoledUp)
- [Aerix Vokototh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/aurils-abode#G19TestofPreservation)
- [Alassar Sulmander](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/caer-dineval#C3KennelandSledStorage)
- [Mere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/caer-dineval#C7GreatHall)

### *Lost Mine of Phandelver* (and *Phandelver and Below: The Shattered Obelisk*)

- [Carp Alderleaf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/lmop/phandalin#AlderleafFarm)
- [Nars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/lmop/phandalin#Captives)

### *Storm King's Thunder*

- [Orok](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#SuggestedEncounter36)

### *Tomb of Annihilation*

- [Prince Na](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tomb-of-annihilation#Mwaxanar%C3%A9andNa)
- [Tahvo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/fane-of-the-night-serpent#PrisonersoftheYuanti)

### *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*

- [Terenzio and Elzerina Cassalanter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/hell-of-a-summer#TerenzioandElzerina)
- [The Three Urchins](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/dragon-season#TheThreeUrchins) – Nat, Jenks, and Squiddly
- [Martem Trec](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/fireball#MartemTrec)

### *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*

- [Delvin Stormshore](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage#10CavesoftheRiverCoven)

### *The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*

- The Lost Children of Loomlurch (Naal, Sung, Philomena, Brottor, Pud, Wendel, Roff, Yevelda, Callybon, Pogo, Mishka)
- The Getaway Gang (Bobi, Sloan, Zennor)
- [Sowpig](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/the-wild-beyond-the-witchlight#WanderingOutsiders) (a ghoul, but arguably a child as well)